# PSD For Universal storyboard

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes, universal-storyboard

Hey my application has universal storyboard with size classes and auto-layout, the designers sends me PSD File but the PSD File is iPhone 5 Layout
i want to know what is the correct way for the designers / developers to use size classes (universal storyboard) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you would like to display UI on iPad. Based on that you can utilise the existing psd.

> A size class is a property applied to any view or view controller that
>   represents the amount of content that can be displayed in a given
>   horizontal or vertical dimension.